# Randomly throwing darts at a dartboard

Tags: probability

I have $x$ darts that I randomly throw on a dartboard with $y$ slots (the v shaped slices like you get when you cut a cake).
Now I select a particular slice on the dartboard . What's the probability that no dart would have hit that slice?

Comment: Success or failure and I suspect independent: [binomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume the whole board is made out of perfectly the same slices and there is no center neutral zone.

Example for y=20

We have 19/20 chances to not hit a dead slice with one dart. With two darts (19/20)^2

So for y darts it would be:
((y-1)/y)^x

Comment: You also assume that each point on the dartboard is equally probable (uniform distribution of dart hits, f'=0 for each point inside the board) and that no dart is thrown outside the board (f=0 outside the board).

Comment: The first statement seems to strong. He only assumes that hitting a slot has equal probability for all slots. Not necessarily a uniform distribution over all possible points on the bord.

Comment: @N74 I dont have ant additional informations. The only changing things are x and y just how OP stated. So I needed to assume that each point has the same probability of being hit. Otherwise thee is no proper solution without something added (more info).

Comment: You can assume that the board is divided into discrete regions and the likelihood of hitting a region is the same for all regions. Which point is hit inside the region is immaterial.